# Different appcatalog for different site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-admin-center, app-catalog

Is there any way to create different appcatalog for different site collection?
If we have sites- https://xx.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite1 and https://xx.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite2 then is it possible to create different appcatalog for each of them?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have a different app catalog for different site collections.

There are two types of App Catalogs.

1. Tenant App Catalog
2. Site Collection App Catalog

You can enable the Site Collection App Catalog using the below commands.

Using Office 365 CLI:

```
spo site appcatalog add --url https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/marketing
```

Using PnP PowerShell:

```
Add-PnPSiteCollectionAppCatalog -site https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<sitename>
```

**References:**

1. [Create Site Collection App Catalog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/site-collection-app-catalog)
2. [Enable Site Collection App Catalog For Particular Site Collection Level Solution/Features](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/enable-site-collection-app-catalog-for-particular-site-collection-level-solution/)

Comment: Did Answer help?